# Pull out specific line

Tags: java

So I am trying to write a program that goes and searches for a specific phrase in a .txt file. If it helps that part of the line is

```
USGController::prepUsgBleed():
```

After I find that I want to pull that whole line from the .txt file into a string in my program. Or even better the numbers that are defined at the end (the 60 and the 679). Here's the line that get's printed out that I want to pull in:

```
17338.353384    [0x00001d40][Default]   USGController::prepUsgBleed(): mA 60 mV 0 mode 1 dac 679
```

Comment: I assume the priority for you is the data and not the Java program itself. If that assumption is correct, you are better of using tools like grep or awk. If you want better control with some scripting, you can use scripting language like perl/ruby/python which is friendlier to code for file and string processing.

Comment: Unfortunately java is the only language I can use for this project. So I can't use python or anything like that

Answer (score 2):

Just read the file line by line with `BufferedReader.readLine()` and use `String.indexOf()` to find the substring.

If `indexOf()` returns a value >= 0, keep the line.